# SCSS syntax error in safari only hack

Tags: css, sass, safari, cross-browser, media-queries

While converting a `.css` file to `.scss` I am getting a Sass syntax error in safari only hack section.

At the following part of the code its throwing `Invalid CSS after "...tio:0) { @media": expected media query (e.g. print, screen, print and screen), was "{"` error.

```
@media screen and (min-color-index:0) and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { @media
{ 
// some code here
}}
```

Comment: why have you got a media query inside your media query?

Answer (score 1):

Your media query is invalid, you have a media query inside your media query which has no conditions.

Try this:

```
@media screen and (min-color-index:0) and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    // some code here
}
```

Comment: followed the safari hacks from https://jeffclayton.wordpress.com/2015/04/28/css-hacks-for-safari-6-1-7-and-8-not-chrome

Comment: I've never seen a media query like that before, pretty weird hack. Do you need it? or does my code work?

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen and (min-color-index:0) and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { @media { // some code here }}
```

should be

```
@media screen and (min-color-index:0) and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { // some code here }}
```

You have a media query inside a media query, which is invalid.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

You can use javascript to properly detect safari, something like this:

```
function isiPad() { return (
(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf(/iPad/i) > -1));}
```